# How do I deal with grass seed blown into a garden bed?

Tags: lawn, weed-control, weeds

With the recent high winds a lot of the grass seed that we put down five days ago for a new lawn has been blown onto fresh new flower beds. Do you have any tips on how best to remove them? The soil is super soft from rain so we don't want to walk on the lawn yet, but are worried the seed will grow in the flower bed where we don't want it!

Comment: Are you averse to using chemicals? There are plenty of preemergents on the market these days.

Answer (score 2):

Would just cover the areas where the seed landed with cardboard after any seed has germinated. Waiting till it has germinated will allow you to get most the grass. Usually cover with a mulch to keep it uniform looking.

Any seeds that are directly in a flower bed plant should be pulled when they germinate.